# optaplanner BendableLongScore with two softScores

Tags: java, optaplanner

Optaplanner BendableLongScore has two softScores. Do the two softScores have a priority level?

I always feel that the first softScore is the priority in the code now. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Bendable(Long)Score with 2 hard levels and 3 soft levels, then you basically have veryHard/hard/medium/soft/verySoft. So yes, there's a priority level.

It's just a bendable score because it's more than 3 levels total and I don't want to create a separate Score for 4 levels, 5 levels, 6 levels and so on.